# How can I continue to move my image right then at a certain position move down

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner JavaScript user. I am making a board game using mostly JavaScript. I am having a hard time making my pawn go down after passing *left: 400px.* My pawn will automatically
goes to *left: 0px* then move down; even after I set it to *left: 400px.*

```
dicedir = "diceimage/"
let x_pos = 100;
let y_pos = 100;
sum = 0;

// My roll() will starts when the button is clicked on
document.getElementById("rollButton").addEventListener("click", roll)

function roll() {
  //dice portion of the function
  randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)
  console.log(randomNumber)

  rollthedice = dicedir + "dice" + randomNumber + ".png"
  console.log(rollthedice)
  document.getElementById("dice").src = rollthedice
  //end of the dice portion of the function


  // pawn postioning 
  blackpawn = document.getElementById("pawn")

  //pawn moving right
  moveright = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
  x_pos += moveright[randomNumber - 1]
  leftrightpos = x_pos + "px"
  console.log(leftrightpos)
  blackpawn.style = "left: " + leftrightpos

  //pawn moving down when its cross left: 400px 
  if (leftrightpos > 400 + "px") {
    blackpawn.style.position = "relative"
    blackpawn.style.left = "400px";
    y_pos += moveright[0]
    upBottompos = y_pos + "px"
    console.log(upBottompos)
    blackpawn.style = "top: " + upBottompos
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, this technically works `leftrightpos > 400 + "px"` because `>` on strings does an alphabetical comparison, so it's checking if `"600px"` comes later in the alphabet than `"400px"`. You should instead compare numbers only, with `if(x_pos > 400)`

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
blackpawn.style = "left: " + leftrightpos


blackpawn.style = "top: " + upBottompos
```

Replace all existing styles with the style you specify.  In other words, the first one *doesn't* say "add a left style" ... it says "remove all other styled, *then* add a left style".

I suspect this is related to your problem.  You should instead use the style (no pun intended) for setting `style` that you used elsewhere, eg.

```
blackpawn.style.left = "400px";
```

Or, in other words, those two lines should become:

```
blackpawn.style.left = leftrightpos


blackpawn.style.top = upBottompos
```